# IntelliSense does not work for JavaScript

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2010, intellisense

While typing, IntelliSense normally offers me a list of matching functions and variables. The one that matches the best is selected - if I hit for example the space bar, the rest of the function/variable name is inserted.
Unfortunatly, this does not seem to work for JavaScript. IntelliSense does offer me a list of functions/variables, but I have to hit [enter] to insert the full word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to open "Tools" => "Options". In the opended dialog select "Text Editor" => "JScript" => "Miscellaneous" from the left column. Now disable the option "Only use Tab or Enter to commit".